# Определение id у нажатого дива или ссылки в скрипте

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

Доброго всем времени суток господа

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="olgaslim/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#buttonUpload").click(function(){
        $.ajax({url:"index.php",type:"POST",cache:true,data:{data:$("#buttonUpload").text()}})
        .done(function(data){
            $("#dataUpload").html(data);
        })
    });
    $("#buttonUploat").click(function(){
        $.ajax({url:"index.php",type:"POST",cache:true,data:{data:$("#buttonUploat").text()}})
        .done(function(data){
            $("#dataUploat").html(data);
        })
    });
});
</script>
```

Имеем 'div' или 'a', с 'id=#buttonUpload'. Нажимаем его - в другом div обновляется информация, на ту, что была в странице куда посылаем POST запрос

Можно ли как то определить нажатый id с в крипте? и сделать конструкцию вроде:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var id = 'как то определяем нажатый id';

    if(нажали == #buttonUpload){
        $("#buttonUpload").click(function(){
            $.ajax({url:"index.php",type:"POST",cache:true,data:{data:$("#buttonUpload").text()}})
            .done(function(data){
                $("#dataUpload").html(data);
            })
        });    
    }

    if(нажали == #buttonUploat){
        $("#buttonUploat").click(function(){
            $.ajax({url:"index.php",type:"POST",cache:true,data:{data:$("#buttonUploat").text()}})
            .done(function(data){
                $("#dataUploat").html(data);
            })
        });    
    }
});
</script>
```

т.е. определить нажатый id, и уже по условию if определять, какой div нужно обновить

Comment: если я правильно вас понял - то $(event.target)

Comment: бгкхм.. вообще то да! Но на практике если записать в скрипте после 

    $(document).ready(function(){
        var id = $(event.target); alert(id);
    ...

то скажем хром выдаст алерт с сообщением не об id, а об 'object OBJECT', что != id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Исходя из приведенного вами участка все можно спростить до

HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:;" id="buttonUpload" data-target="dataUpload">uploaD</a>
<a href="javascript:;" id="buttonUploat" data-target="dataUploat">uploaT</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#buttonUploat, #buttonUpload").click(function(){ //Хотя, раз пошло такое движение, то можно уже ссылкам дать класс и навешивать клик по селектору ".className"
        var self = $(this);
        $.ajax({
          url:"index.php",
          type:"POST",
          cache:true,
          data:{data: self.text()}
        }).done(function(data){
          $("#" + self.data("target")).html(data); //
        });
    });
});
```